# create a html background video that comes to the foreground on buttonpress using z index.

Tags: javascript, css, html

i have been trying to create a html background video that comes to the foreground on buttonpress using z index.

my html code:

```
<div id="vidarea" class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video autoplay loop muted poster="altimg.jpg" id="bgvid" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="tester5.mp4 " type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
</div>
<div id= "buttonpause">
    <button id="vidpause">Pause</button>    
</div>
```

my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid"),
pauseButton = document.getElementById("vidpause");
function vidFade() {
    vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}
vid.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    // only functional if "loop" is removed 
     vid.pause();
    // to capture IE10
    vidFade();
});
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
    if (vid.paused) {
vid.play();
        pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
        vid.pause();
        pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){   
       $("bgvid").bind('ended', function(){
          location.href="indexmobi.html";   
       }); 
      });

</script>
```

my css:

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(altimg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

The code i have only plays it on the background and pauses it on buttonpress.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.

Comment: im stuck on how to add my media docs like the video so as to run the code in jsfiddle any ideas how thats done?